# Unable to view videos on facebook and youtube due to older flash player version

Tags: adobe, upgrade, flash, ubuntu-10.04

I've been trying this for a long time now and so couldn't help but posting this question-
Upgrading or even downloading latest flash player versions is the trouble.

I tried the simplest way on the link-
https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

After selecting my computer version APT for Ubuntu and clicking on Download,a pop up box asks for an application to choose to open the download link.I just cant figure what the application should be.

Can you suggest something for it?

I also tried the terminal way for it-
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
which gave an error message-"broken count >0" saying that installed packages have unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not the right place for such questions, you should post on [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), but never the less, since i have the same problem i can share this:

are you using firefox? if so the problem is not you, is adobe. I am guessing that you have an out dated version of flash player, because adobe is not supporting flash for linux after v11.2 (read [here](http://www.adobe.com/gr_en/products/flashplayer/tech-specs.html) and here [under linux paragraph](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/whitepapers/roadmap.html))

Supposedly there is still support for chrome browser, but i can not confirm since i havent switched to chrome yet(if i ever will)

ps. you should update your ubuntu, 10.04 has reached its end of life on [9 May 2013](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2013-March/000169.html)

Comment: advice for upgrading ubuntu taken into consideration .

Comment: however if you could just suggest the application to choose from the link I provided , it would be really helpful. Thankyou anyway.